# Change Countdown time to 13:30

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I want to modify my Countdown to `13:30`, instead of `16:00`.

```html
<td>
    <strong>Order before 15:30</strong>
    <span><br>and your order is sent today</span>
</td>
```

```js
$("strong:contains('Order before 15:30')").attr("id","countdown").delay(1000);

function ShowTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    var offset = now.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

    now.setHours(now.getHours() + (offset+1));
    if (now.getHours() < 16) {
        var hrs = 15-now.getHours();
        var mins = 59-now.getMinutes();
        var secs = 59-now.getSeconds();

        if (hrs < 10) 
            hrs = "0" + hrs;

        if (mins < 10)     
            mins = "0" + mins;

        if (secs < 10) 
            secs = "0" + secs;

        timeLeft = 'Order within <span style="color: #ff713d; font-size: larger">' + hrs + 'h ' + mins + 'm ' + secs + 's</span>';
        $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
        $("span:contains('and your order is sent today')").html("<br />and your package is sent today")
    }
}

var day = new Date().getDay(); 
if (day != 0 && day != 6) {
    setInterval(ShowTime, 1000);
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hga7kcvy/1/)

How would I achieve this? Changing these parameters returns me error?

```
var hrs = 13 - now.getHours();
var mins = 29 - now.getMinutes();
var secs = 29 - now.getSeconds();
```

Comment: Your code works fine when you use what you describe as giving you an error: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/hga7kcvy/4/. What error do you get? It would seem unrelated to the code you've shown.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan do you see the 0-2m in the middle?

Comment: That's because you're subtracting the current minutes, `39`, from `29` and getting a negative number.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan where do the substraction happen? do you understand how to achieve the result towards an half hour?

Comment: _“where do the substraction happen?”_ – at the point where you calculate the initial values for `mins` …? // If you subtract a value that is greater than the existing one, then you need to subtract 1 unit from the next “level” as well – so if you subtract 39 minutes from 29, then you need to a) “equalize” the result by adding 60 (so that you end up with 10 minutes) and b) decrease the hour by one as well.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan got it working now

Answer (score 1):

```
function ShowTime(hour, min) {
    var now = new Date();
    var offset = now.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

    now.setHours(now.getHours() + (offset+1));
    if (now.getHours() <= hour) {
        var hrs = ((hour-1)%24)-now.getHours();
        var mins = ((min-1)%60)-now.getMinutes();
        var secs = 59-now.getSeconds();
```

But you'll need to improve it a bit to make sure it works properly even when you "mean" the next day (now it's 18:00, and you want to count down 'till 06:00 the next day)

You should call the function with the hour, min arguments:

```
setInterval(function(){ShowTime(16,00)}, 1000);
```

Comment: Unchaught TypeError, modify how? What way?

Comment: What kind of improvements does it need?

Comment: it counts for me now, but you'll need to change the calculations, because if now it's 13:34 and you count 'til 14:30, then the you'll see 1 hour and -4 minutes. A better approach when you deal with dates, times is to do all the calculations on timestamps. Calculate left_ts=alarm_ts - now_ts, then display the hours, minutes simply like: h=left_ts/(3600000), m-(left_ts%3600000)/1000

Comment: My pleasure. I'd appreciate if you can accept the answer